# Navigating back from a root page to a tabbed page causes weird flickering

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

The app is simple, it combines side menu and tab. I thought it works flawlessly but not until I discovered that navigating to a `root page` then hitting the Browser previous button causes a weird flickering of the nav bar.

This is the [output](https://www.useloom.com/share/4d3a7bd42b024f16a49716eebcaf7ab0) I am getting so far.

**Menu.ts**

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

export interface PageInterface {
    title: string;
    pageName: string;
    tabComponent?: any;
    index?: number;
    icon: string;
}

// Am I doing some mistakes in the following block? 
@IonicPage({
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.html'
})

export class MenuPage {

    rootPage ="TabsPage";

    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    pages: PageInterface[]= [
        { title:'Tab 1', pageName: 'TabsPage', tabComponent: 'HomePage', index: 0, icon:'home' },
        { title:'Tab 2', pageName: 'TabsPage', tabComponent: 'SchedulePage', index: 1, icon:'timer' },
        { title:'Tab 3', pageName: 'TabsPage', tabComponent: 'CasesPage', index: 2, icon:'briefcase' },
    { title:'Non-Tab', pageName: 'SplashPage', icon:'information-circle' }
        ]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  openPage(page: PageInterface) {
    let params = {};

    if (page.index) {
      params = { tabIndex: page.index};
    }

    if (this.nav.getActiveChildNavs().length && page.index != undefined) {
        this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0].select(page.index);
        console.log('Else executed umdefined');
    } else {
      // This is where I set new root page if it is not a tabbed page.
    this.nav.setRoot(page.pageName, params).catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(`Didn't set nav root: ${err}`);
      });
    }
  }

  isActive(page: PageInterface) {
    let childNav = this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0];

    if (childNav) {
      if (childNav.getSelected() && childNav.getSelected().root === page.tabComponent) {
        return 'primary';
      }
      return;
    }

    if (this.nav.getActive() && this.nav.getActive().name === page.pageName) {
      return 'primary';
    }
     return;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('MenuPage');
  }
}
```

**Tabs.ts**

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'page-tabs'
})
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

    tab1Root= 'HomePage';
    tab2Root= 'SchedulePage';
    tab3Root= 'CasesPage';
    myIndex: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

}
```

The whole project is available [here](https://github.com/jjjhanreyyy/Prosecutor-App) if the info is not sufficient.

**Update**
I can't explain clearer but if you try to run the project and observe the URL as you switch from a tabbed to non-tabbed page the issue seems to be from the history of navigation.

Comment: have you tested on a device?

Comment: is there a reason you use `@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;` instead of `navCtrl`?

Comment: @ewizard Tested it on Ionic DevApp and the flickering happens. Same with Chrome.

Comment: I really am starting to learn Ionic. The Ionic Conference App uses @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav; so I did follow. How should I use navCtrl instead of @ViewChild?

Comment: maybe it's just me but it seems to be resetting the hamburger icon if not the side menu...have you tried toggling with navroot with just side menu and no tabs?

Comment: @SurajRao The issue does not occur when in a non-tabbed page like the about page. As of the moment I tried pushing the non-tabbed page instead of setting it as a new root and no flickering can be seen.

Comment: maybe think of raising an issue in github.. I _think_ menu is resetting but I have no way of confirming this.

Comment: Will do, but can you check out the source code I put. I really think that I am missing something so obvious that it causes this flickering.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts file, set the rootPage value as

rootPage: 'MenuPage'

and in your menu.ts file, set the rootPage value as

rootPage: 'HomePage' (or whatever Page you want to show in Tab).

This approach works fine for me

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It seems that you have not thoroughly assessed the question or the source before answering.